# Access RichTextContentControl Text from an AddIn in MS Word using C#

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I've created an AddIn for MS Word. There's a new tab and a button. I've added a new template document that has a RichTextContentControl in it.

```
 WORD_APP = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oTemplate = "E:\\Sandbox\\TemplateWithFields\\TemplateWithFields\\TemplateWithFields.dotx";
            oDoc = WORD_APP.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

I want to get the text inside the RichTextContentControl. How can I access the text or content of a RichTextContentControl in my AddIn project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the content control can be accessed as follows:

```
string text = contentControl1.Range.Text;
```

Additionally, there are a number of ways you can iterate through content controls and only select content controls of specific type or content controls which match a certain tag or title.

This is quite important as you may want to process only content controls which match a specific type or naming convention, please see an example below:

```
        WORD_APP = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oTemplate = "E:\\Sandbox\\TemplateWithFields\\TemplateWithFields\\TemplateWithFields.dotx";
        Word.Document document = WORD_APP.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        //Iterate through ALL content controls
        //Display text only if the content control is of type rich text
        foreach (Word.ContentControl contentControl in document.ContentControls)
        {
            if (contentControl.Type == Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(contentControl.Range.Text);
            }
        }

        //Only iterate through content controls where the tag is equal to "RT_Controls"
        foreach (Word.ContentControl contentControl in document.SelectContentControlsByTag("RT_Controls"))
        {
            if (contentControl.Type == Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Selected by tag - " + contentControl.Range.Text);
            }
        }

        //Only iterate through content controls where the title is equal to "Title1"
        foreach (Word.ContentControl contentControl in document.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Title1"))
        {
            if (contentControl.Type == Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Selected by title - " + contentControl.Range.Text);
            }
        }
```